# Is it possible to get the index status (Index Coverage report in new version) from Google Search Console via the API

Tags: r, google-search-console, google-index

So my issue is that I would like to get the index status from Google search console via the API (see picture below):

[image: Index status]

I think it's called the Index coverage report in the new Google Search console version. 
Regardless, is it possible to get this number via the API? I checked their documentation : https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/  and the answer seems to be not really.

Wanted to see if anyone has experience with this (ideally in R but hey I'll take anything :) ). I mainly want to know if it is possible, and if so if there is an example / technical documentation on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible via the API, if its not on this [list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/).  The only other option you could try would be to scrape the value by using `rvest` but that is most likely not going to work long term (and check its not against ToS)

Answer (score 0):

It's not available in API anymore, as said here by Google:

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/01/focusing-on-new-search-console.html

> Along with the Crawl Errors report, we're also deprecating the crawl errors API that's based on the same internal systems. At the moment, we don't have a replacement for this API. We'll inform API users of this change directly.

Comment: Link only answer will lose its value when the link is broken in future, please add the relevant context from the link into answer.